# annular section click event

Tags: javascript, math, random, geometry

I need to know, given the point coordinates (x,y) inside the annular sections highlighted (for simplicity with rectangles), if the user clicked the red/orange/blue/purple/yellow or green area.

can't find the equation for the point calculation.

[image: annulus circonference]

Comment: I think a way to to this is to play with (co)sinus to calculate the angle between the center of your ring (called the [0,0] point) and decuce the color.

Comment: I want also the inner circle be not clickable

Comment: easy : calculate the inner and outer circle radius and compare it with the length of your vector (x1 = 0, x2 = your x, y1 = 0, y2 = your y) => `sqrt((x2-x1)² + (y2 - y1)²)`. And this size (L) must be : inner radius < L < outer radius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Yoplaboom says in comments, I would calculate the angle, then divide the areas by degrees and check in which area was the click.

Take a look at this simplification of your problem:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#back').click(function(e) {
        var innerR = 50;
     var centerX = 150; 
        var centerY = 150; 
        var posX = $(this).position().left;
        var posY = $(this).position().top;
        deltaX = (e.pageX - posX)-centerX;
        deltaY = centerY-(e.pageY - posY);
        var rad = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
        var deg = rad * (180 / Math.PI);
      
        var d = Math.sqrt( Math.pow(deltaX,2) + Math.pow(deltaY,2) );
        if (d < innerR) return;
        
        if (0<deg && deg<90){
            alert("green");
        }
        else if(90<deg && deg<180){
          alert("red");
        }
        else if(0>deg && deg>-90){
          alert("blue");
        }
        else if(90>deg && deg>-180){
          alert("yellow");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#back { 
width:300px;
height:300px; 
background-color: #fffffa;
  position:relative
}
#red { 
width:150px;
height:150px;
float: left;
background-color: red;
}
#green { 
width:150px;
height:150px;
float: left;
background-color: green;
}
#yellow { 
width:150px;
height:150px;
float: left;
background-color: yellow;
}
#blue { 
width:150px;
height:150px;
float: left;
background-color: blue;
}
#center{
position: absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  top:100px;
  left:100px;
  background:white;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="back" >
  <div id="red"></div>
  <div id="green"></div>
  <div id="yellow"></div>
  <div id="blue"></div>
  <div id="center"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you almost got the problem. I need also, not to get the center of the circle. I mean, if someone clicks "close" to the center (ie. outside the ring, inside the circle) I don't want the alert to be printed out. maybe include into the if statement, if the distance from the center is included in the colored area

Comment: You can check the update, in which I calculate the distance to an inner radius and I check if the click position is greater than that. I'm sure you will be able to make something similar with the outer radius of the ring.